# Access a property of a list when using CreateMap with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to access a property of a list, I'm to using a custom resolver that maps two booleans to and converts those booleans into an array.

```
x.CreateMap<List<CouponCsvItem>, List<Coupon>>()
.ConvertUsing(x=>x.SchoolType, opt=>opt.MapFrom(new SchoolResolver()));
```

I like to access that property but since both types are lists I can't, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you create a mapping from `CouponCsvItem` to `Coupon`? AutoMapper has a build-in support for lists, you don't need to re-implement a mapping of lists. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: thanks for pointing into the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a map of single objects and AutoMapper will handle the lists cases as well.

```
x.CreateMap<CouponCsvItem, Coupon>()
    .ConvertUsing(x => x.SchoolType, opt => opt.MapFrom(new SchoolResolver()));
```